# trouble running rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I was trying to run rspec, but got following error.

```
/Users/xy/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p551/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.9.4/lib/bundler.rb:317: warning: Insecure world writable dir /usr/local/bin in PATH, mode 040777
/Users/xy/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p551/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.9.4/lib/bundler.rb:317: warning: Insecure world writable dir /usr/local/bin in PATH, mode 040777
You are using Curb 0.7.10. WebMock supports version >= 0.7.16.
DEPRECATION WARNING: ActiveSupport::Memoizable is deprecated and will be removed in future releases,simply use Ruby memoization pattern instead. (called from extend at /Users/xy/ht-webapp12/config/initializers/mysql2_column_cache.rb:3)
/Users/xy/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p551/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/mysql2-0.3.11/lib/mysql2/client.rb:44:in `connect': Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock' (2) (Mysql2::Error)
```

Does anyone know how to fix it?

Comment: can you update the question with the content of the Gemfile and Gemfile.lock ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try with:

```
bundle exec rspec
```

problem is if you don't run rspec with bundle, it will use your latest system libraries which may have different versions from the one you have bundled in your project

---

after reading your answer, update your Gemfile to make curb to be greater than `0.7.16`, I can give you the right directions after I see your `Gemfile` and `Gemfile.lock`.

But you should check the content of the Gemfile.lock, and check where `curb` is being loaded with which version, just check the libraries that depends on it and update those libraries, that will update your curb, otherwise you can add curb as a requirement on Gemfile with the desider versions, other libraries may compalin but you should be able to fix the conflicts.

If you don't want any of those approaches, just downgrade rspec to an earlier version which works with older versions of curb.

Comment: I did run using bundle exec rspec

Comment: can you update the question with the content of the Gemfile and Gemfile.lock ?

Comment: I can't. But why rspec even need sql since fixture already has the sample data?

Comment: rspec loads your complete application, on your application you define the Gemfile with the libraries that it needs but those libraries needs other libraries and you can see the tree of libraries being loaded on Gemfile.lock, if you don't want something to be loaded on rspec, don't define it on the default group on Gemfile and instead define it for the groups development, production, etc. but not for the test group